How can I scroll to bottom of element after swap?
I would like to go to the last todo item after adding it, but I can't get it to work.
Here's the code:
<button 
    id="button"
    hx-post="/api/todos" 
    hx-include="#field-description, #field-amount"
    hx-target="#todos-container" 
    hx-swap="innerHTML"
    hx-on:click="
        document.getElementById('field-description').value = '';
        document.getElementById('field-amount').value = '';
        document.getElementById('field-description').focus();
    "
    hx-on::afterSwap="document.getElementById('todos').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' });"
>
    Add
</button>


Have you looked at the scroll modifier for the hx-swap attribute? If so, doesn't it do what you need?

Based on @McPherson's comment I adjusted your code so that it scrolls. I removed your Javascript events and replaced them with the scroll modifier, that is instead of
hx-swap="innerHTML"

it's now
hx-swap="innerHTML scroll:bottom"

Below is an interactive demo demonstrating scrolling. It includes a mock endpoint for /api/todos and some CSS used to make the scrolling effect more obvious. I tried to guess what other elements you might have based on the fields in your button and I moved the field resets to the form element instead of resetting them one-by-one.


<!-- load demo environment -->
<script src="https://demo.htmx.org/demo.js"></script>

<!-- your modified code -->
<div id="todos">
  <form hx-on::after-request="this.reset()">
    <label>Description:
        <input id="field-description" type="text"></label>
    <label>Amount:
        <input id="field-amount" type="number"></label>

    <button
            id="button"
            hx-post="/api/todos"
            hx-include="#field-description, #field-amount"
            hx-target="#todos-container"
            hx-swap="innerHTML scroll:bottom"
            >
            Add
    </button>
  </form>

  <ul id="todos-container"></ul>
</div>

<!-- styles to make the scrolling more obvious in the demo -->
<style>
  #todos-container {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 3rem;
    overflow: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
</style>

<!-- mock endpoint to render todo items -->
<template url="/api/todos">
    ${todo(this["field-description"].value, this["field-amount"].value)}
</template>
<!-- extra logic to output list of all todos as innerHTML as in the
question asker's example -->
<script>
  let todo = function() {
    todos = []
    return (desc, amt) => {
      todos.push(`<li>${desc} (${amt})`)
      return todos.join('')
    }
  }()
</script>



